# How to fix "More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES' error in Android

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, google-drive-api

i'm migrating to google drive api v3 and updated dependencies according to this [sample](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/android-samples/blob/master/drive/deprecation/app/build.gradle) like this :

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.26.0'
implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.26.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev136-1.25.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
```

but i'm facing to this error:

> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'

and can not run the app

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `packagingOptions` `pickFirst` or `exclude`; think it should be save to exclude it:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        // pickFirst "META-INF/DEPENDENCIES"
        exclude "META-INF/DEPENDENCIES"
    }
}
```

There also seems to be a version mismatch in between `1.25.0` and `1.26.0`. Current version is :

```
implementation "com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev173-1.25.0"
```

and the others might need to have version `1.25.0`, too.

Comment: could u explain why adding this solve the problem, what mean of  META-INF/DEPENDENCIES?

Comment: What does the error message say? And `META-INF/DEPENDENCIES` is only required for JAR.